# Open a form to a record selected in a subform

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, subform, openform

I want to open a form to the record selected in the subform of a different form.  I've tried following what I’ve seen in other posts about this, but I still can't get it to work.  I think I'm just missing some very basic detail but this is my first Access database and I can't figure out what it is.  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

**Details:**

- F_Detail - *(This is a Single Form containing details on a project.)*
- F_List - *(This is a Single Form containing a subform and a button.)*
- subF_List - *(This is the subform contained in F_List.  This subform is in Datasheet view)*
- Project_ID - *(This is the primary key contained in subF_List and in F_Detail.  It is the common criteria between the two.  It is Short Text type.)*

subF_List displays row after row of projects.  F_Detail displays details about a single project at a time.  From F_List I want to select a row in subF_List and then click the button to open F_Detail, and F_Detail will be displaying details of the project whose row was selected in subF_List when I pressed the button.

**What I Have for the Button**:
On Click > Event Procedure

```
    Private Sub ProjectDetailButton_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Detail",,,"Project_ID = " & Me.Project_ID

    End Sub
```

Upon clicking the button, I get an error saying, "Compile error: Method or data member not found" and it highlights the .Project_ID at the end of my code.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any help you can lend.  Please let me know if I've left out any needed detail.

Comment: Is there really no space between `&` and `Me.Project_ID`? That should actually fail when typing the VBA.

Comment: There is a space between those items.  I've edited my original post to correct this.  Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Do I need to do something different to call out the fact that the selected record is in a subform, as opposed to being in the form itself?

Comment: I just noticed you say Project_ID is text, not number. Text field parameters must have apostrophe delimiters: `"Project_ID = '" & Me.Project_ID & "'"`. However, I would have expected a different error message.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked when I added it to the doubleclick event for a field in the Datasheet Subform.  It still did not work when I added it to the event for the Single Form's button, though.  I wonder if it may have to do with ME. no longer referring to the subform record once I've clicked the button?  I'm content with the doubleclick for my database, but I would still like to find the answer to the button just for archiving the solution on this site.

Comment: Button is on main form? Isn't there a field there with the project identifier?

Comment: Button is on main form, but record is located in subform.  Project_ID is a field in the subform and in the second form that I am attempting to open, but Project_ID is not in the main form, itself.

Comment: Main form is unbound with a subform and subsubform?

Answer (score 0):

Use apostrophe delimiters for text field parameters. Use # for date/time, nothing for number.

`"Project_ID = '" & Me.Project_ID & "'"`

`Me` is alias for form or report the code is behind. To reference a field in its RecordSource:

`Me!Project_ID`

Code on main form referencing field on subform must reference through subform container control. I always name container different from object it holds, such as `ctrProjects`:

`Me.ctrProjects!Project_ID`

I name controls different from fields they are bound to, such as `tbxProject`:

`Me.ctrProjects.Form.tbxProject`